# How values are parsed to this insert function in haskell

Tags: haskell, insert, set

I am trying to figure out this piece of code that how it is actually working. This function implementing the concept of Set in Haskell.

I have a general concept about set in Haskell that it is just like a function which is (type IntSet = a -> Bool) but i dont really understand the purpose of using this i mean it is just like another simple function and logic behind inserting is, if you want to insert an element into the set you just extend the characteristic function to include case for that.

Here i am trying to understand this insert function that how to parse values to insert function and also insert element into it.

```
type IntSet = Int -> Bool
```

If we have an empty set if we want to insert values into this it will always return False because it doesn't contain the value, Understandable! but how to insert value and see its actually inserted.

```
empty :: IntSet 
empty = \ _ -> False 

insert :: Int -> IntSet -> IntSet 
insert x s = \y -> x ==y then True else s y 


input : insert 2 empty 0



result = False
```

How values are parsed to insert function and what is the value of `s` `x` and `y` and in else case when it returns `s y` how this is handled.

I am just a beginner, any valuable input would be appreciated.

Comment: `x` is `2`, `s` is `empty` and `y` is `0`.

Comment: Thankyou and what if i want to insert an element into the set and see it is inserted or not how can i see that?

Comment: @Sniper If the value `x` has been inserted into a set `s` (that is, it is a member of `s`), then `s x == True`. That's the whole concept behind this definition of sets: a set here is just a function from values to `Bool`s which returns `True` for a value `x` if that value is in the set, and returns `False` otherwise.

Comment: The word here should be “passed,” not “parsed”. “Parsed” means something very different.

Answer (score 2):

This represents a set as a function that, given an `Int`, tells you if it is in the et (by returning `True`) or not (by returning `False`).

The empty set is thus the function that returns `False` no matter what argument you give.

Inserting into a set means returning a new set/function based on the old set/function.

There is a minor typo in your function definition, as it is missing the `if` keyword:

```
insert :: Int -> IntSet -> IntSet
insert x s = \y -> if x == y then True else s y
```

When you insert some new value `x` into a set, you are getting back a new set returns `True` if the just inserted value is queried, or else defers the answer to the old set. For example,

```
let newset = insert 3 empty in newset 3
```

evaluates to `True` because

```
newset 3 == (insert 3 empty) 3
         == (\y -> if 3 == y then True else empty 3) 3
         == if 3 == 3 then True else empty 3
         == True
```

while `let newset = insert 3 empty in newset 4` returns `False` because

```
newset 4 == (insert 3 empty) 4
         == (\y -> if 3 == y then True else empty 3) 4
         == if 4 == 3 then True else empty 3
         == empty 3
         == (\_ -> False) 3
         == False
```

This works fine (albeit a bit inefficiently) for querying a particular value. But what if you just want to see all the values contained in the set? Conceptually, it's easy (since `Int` is finite, so are all the possible sets): just filter the list of all `Int` values using the set/function:

```
setToList :: IntSet -> [Int]
setToList s = filter s [minBound..maxBound]
```

Given something like `setToList (insert 3 (insert 5 empty))`, it is straightforward (though tedious) to show that

- `(insert 3 (insert 5 empty)) minBound` is False,
- `(insert 3 (insert 5 empty)) (minBound + 1)` is False,
- ...
- `(insert 3 (insert 5 empty)) 0` is False,
- `(insert 3 (insert 5 empty)) 1` is False,
- `(insert 3 (insert 5 empty)) 2` is False,
- `(insert 3 (insert 5 empty)) 3` is True,
- etc,

  so that the final result is the list `[3, 5]`. It takes a while, though, because depending on your system, the list `[minBound..maxBound]` could have quite a few elements. (Check the values of `minBound :: Int` and `maxBound :: Int` to see just how many.)

---

Note that `setToList` only terminates because `Int` is a finite type.